# Check permissions of a non-existent file in java

Tags: java, file, permissions

I want to do something like:

```
if (!file.canWrite())
  throw Exception("Permission denied");
file.mkdirs();
```

However, I can't do this because `canWrite` only works for files which already exist. Is there a way to tell if I would be able to write to a file, if it existed?

---

EDIT: Thank you, I realize I could check if the file exists. As those of you who read the third line of code will realize, my problem is that `mkdirs` will simply return `false` if it couldn't create the directory - no explanation of why creation failed.

Additionally, `mkdirs` will create files nested arbitrarily deeply. So I'd need something like:

```
while(file.hasParent()){
  file = file.parent();
  if (!file.canWrite()) throw (..);
}
```

As Paul pointed out, I would need to know the umask too.

Comment: `Is there a way to tell if I would be able to write to a file, if it existed?` I don't think so...

Comment: Consider checking the permissions of the directory.

Comment: Check the directory; that's what defines write permissions, no? Otherwise not really, because the file could be created with its own permissions.

Comment: @Dave: What if it's nested arbitrarily deep in non-existent directories? Is there no better way than writing a for loop over all of them?

Comment: As well as the permissions on the directory, you also need to know the umask.  I don't think there is a n easy way to do this.

Comment: @Xodarap - now you're just getting absurd. If the directories don't exist, you can't write to them. Because they don't exist.

Comment: @BrianRoach: Please look up what [mkdirs does](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs()) before saying I'm absurd...

Comment: @Xodarap You can't check the permissions of a directory that may exist later, because it can be created with arbitrary permissions.

Answer (score 2):

Do the same thing, but on the directory instead. The directory write permissions dictate who can and can't write a file to that directory.

Comment: What if it's immediate parent directory also doesn't exist? `mkdirs` allows an arbitrary nesting of non-existent directories.

Comment: But you can have file permissions that are different than the directory permissions.

Comment: @Brian - For that to happen, the file would have to exist, which isn't what he asked ... though it's now starting to verge on the absurd.

Comment: @Xodarap - `mkdir` isn't magic, it's code. Code that breaks apart something like `/first/second/third` and checks each in order to see if it exists or not, creating what it needs to when permissions allow.

Answer (score 2):

You can first check if the file exists:

```
boolean exists = file.exists();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't test permissions on something that doesn't exist.  You can however do a test to see if the item exists and if so then check the permissions.